# Unconditional use of conditional expression for default assignment

Tags: javascript, reactjs, eslint

I'm getting the following linting error: `Unconditional use of conditional expression for default assignment`

What is wrong with the below?

```
(myOverride) ? myOverride : MAGIC_HOST,
```

Where if myOverride is defined I want to use myOverride, if it is not defined I want to use the env var `MAGIC_HOST`.

Comment: How is that expression actually used? Like, where does it appear in the code?

Comment: Define "not defined". Not declared at all? Declared but with the value `undefined`? Declared and you want *all* falsy values to be replaced with `MAGIC_HOST`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Apparently you're using ESLint (as that error is an ESLint) error. It's because of the [`no-unneeded-ternary` rule](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-unneeded-ternary) which is meant to flag up *unnecessary* use of the conditional operator (they call it the "ternary")¹. From the linked docs:

> Another common mistake is using a single variable as both the conditional test and the consequent. In such cases, the logical OR can be used to provide the same functionality. Here is an example:
>
> ```
> // Bad
> var foo = bar ? bar : 1;
>
> // Good
> var foo = bar || 1;
> ```

So the rule is telling you to use `myOverride || MAGIC_HOST` instead.²

You don't *have* to, the code you've shown isn't *wrong*. It's just it doesn't pass that ESLint rule.

---

¹ *"they call it the 'ternary'"* - The conditional operator is **a** ternary operator (an operator accepting three operands, just like `*` is a binary operator — an operator accepting two operands). And it is, **for now**, the only ternary operator JavaScript has. But that doesn't necessarily always have to be true as the language evolves. It's correctly called the [*conditional* operator](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-conditional-operator).

² Depending on what the valid values for `myOverride` are, you may or may not want `myOverride ?? MAGIC_HOST` these days. The difference is that with [`??`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing), **only** the values `null` and `undefined` are replaced with `MAGIC_HOST`, but with [`||`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_OR) any [falsy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy) value is replaced with `MAGIC_HOST`. For a string, you may want to stick with `||`, but it's good to know your options.

Answer (score 3):

It is not inherently *wrong*, but it is better written as:

```
myOverride || MAGIC_HOST
```

as explained [here](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-unneeded-ternary).

Answer (score 0):

Little bit safer is to use : nullish operator `??` instead of a logical operator `||`